# postgres unnest json array given criteria

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I'm new to json arrays in general, but specifically postgresql and looking for some guidance -

I have a table like this -

```
indicator    array
1           [["abc","snow"],"abc","rain"]]
2           [["abc","snow"],["efg","snow"],["abc","rain"],["efg","rain"]]
```

So, I'd like to extract out the letters based on the indicator. If 1 then "abc", if 2 then "abc" and "efg". Like this -

```
indicator     array                                                          output
1           [["abc","snow"],"abc","rain"]]                                    abc
2           [["abc","snow"],["efg","snow"],["abc","rain"],["efg","rain"]]     abc,efg
```

Thank you for any guidance

Answer (score 1):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0d86a82e317968bad0c945504ab1029f)

```
SELECT
    indicator,
    data,
    string_agg(DISTINCT elem ->> 0, ',')    -- 3
FROM mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements(data) as elem      -- 1
GROUP BY indicator, data                    -- 2
```

1. Extract all array elements into an own record
2. Reaggregate them using the following aggregation:
3. a) Get the first array element as text (`->> 0`) b) remove duplicates using `DISTINCT` c) aggregate as string list using `string_agg()`

Comment: thank you for quick response! in trying it out, i'm having a mismatched input error - ```mismatched input '>'. Expecting: <expression>```

Comment: As you can see in the fiddle, this works there. Please try to construct your problem in the fiddle so that I can have a look at it.

Comment: i do see that works and problem seems to be constructed properly, but unsure why it isn't translating for me. just doing this i get a mismatched input error ```SELECT *
FROM mytable, jsonb_array_elements(data)```

Comment: this is the output from type ```array(row(id varchar, weather varchar))```

Comment: you need to cast your weather into type jsonb: `weather::jsonb` where I am using `data`... I guess...

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the comments was helpful to understand fiddle and how that works there, thank you!  However, it didn't quite work for my use case so I put this together that ultimately solved it for me. Maybe a little more roundabout, but works fine.

for splitting JSON array column into 2:

```
select indicator,data 
split_part(replace(replace(replace(json_format(cast(array_agg(DISTINCT id as JSON)), '[', ''), ']', ''), '"', ''),',',1)  as id_1,
split_part(replace(replace(replace(json_format(cast(array_agg(DISTINCT id) as JSON)), '[', ''), ']', ''), '"', ''),',',2)  as id_2
from mytable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(data) as (id, weather)
```

for a single column:

```
select indicator,data 
replace(replace(replace(json_format(cast(array_agg(DISTINCT id) as JSON)), '[', ''), ']', ''), '"', '')  as id_new
from mytable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(data) as (id, weather)
```